# How a cookie consent manager is created?

Tags: javascript, cookieconsent

I want to ask you if somebody know how a cookie consent manager is created? For example OneTrust? They have the banner with accept / reject ok but how they scan cookies automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Onetrust for example scans all the pages in their portal and then identify which cookie is created on each page. They identify as well the source of the script and add it to the OtAutoBlock list with the cookie specific category id.
The scan is done manually in their platform.
I assume it is the same for the other cookie consent manager.